# How do i evaluate this limit as n goes to infinity $(8n- \frac{1}{n})^{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}}$

Tags: limits

How do i evaluate this limit as $n \to \infty$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(8n- \frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}}$$

Thanks

Comment: If there is a limit, it would have to be $1$, because when $n$ is even, it is greater than $1$ and when $n$ is odd, it is less than $1$. That doesn't mean there is a limit, however...

Comment: Split the cases $n$ odd and $n$ even, bring outside $(8n)^\text{stuff...}$ and recall that $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}x^{-\alpha}\ln x=0\qquad\text{ for }\alpha>0$$

Comment: @Taylor can you explain how you attempted to solve the problem?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli so answer is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For even $\;n\;$ :

$$1\le\left(8n-\frac1n\right)^\frac1{n^2}\le(8n)^{\frac1{n^2}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

For odd $\;n\;$:

$$1\xleftarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac1{(8n)^{\frac1{n^2}}}\le\left(8n-\frac1n\right)^{-\frac1{n^2}}=\frac1{\left(8n-\frac1n\right)^\frac1{n^2}}\le 1$$

Comment: so answer is 1.

Comment: Yes, but can you prove it? The above should suffice.